# Fedora primary monitor selection

Tags: fedora

I have machine with Fedora Linux (Schroedinger's cat) 19 with AMD Radeon HD 6800 graphic card. Now, I have monitor plugged in using DVI port and I have TV connected using HDMI port. When machine is booting, the TV is automatically selected as primary screen, but I would like to have my Monitor (DVI port) selected as primary screen and TV (HMDI port) as secondary screen. How do I tell that to Fedora?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the command `xrandr` to configure which device is the primary etc. See this wiki article titled: [Xrandr](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Xrandr) on the Gentoo wiki for several examples.

#### Examples

```
$ xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1024x768
$ xrandr --output DVI-0 --auto --left-of LVDS
$ xrandr --output LVDS --primary
```

See the man page for `xrandr` for more on how to use it.