# Setting primary monitor in XFCE?

Tags: xfce, multi-monitor

I have two monitors:

```
------   ------
|VGA-1| |HDMI-1|
------  --------
```

for some reason VGA-1 defaults to the primary monitor. Now this is what I have tried to fix this:

1. Go to settings edit and set primary on HDMI-1 to True
2. This: [Fedora primary monitor selection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99558/fedora-primary-monitor-selection)
   Now it seems it did a trick since HDMI-1 is primary according to "xrandr --current". However the panel is still on the left (VGA-1) monitor and I'm not sure that my HDMI-1 is primary at all.

Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Right click the panel, go to 'Panel preferences'. You'll have a dropdown for 'Output'. Change this from 'Automatic' to the display you want it to show up on. By default it will be on the left-most monitor.

[image: xfce panel preferences]

Comment: This works only for panel placement, not for primary display selection.
Primary display is the display where were all the windows before the additional display was connected.

Comment: For me, windows pop up on whatever display the mouse cursor is on. I forget what controls this though.

Comment: Popping up is not related to primary/secondary/tertiary display.

Comment: In fact this got worse when connecting third monitor (left is for VGA, middle is for notebook screen and right is for DisplayPort - the left/top display always grabs the Panel.

Comment: Changing this from `Automatic` to `Primary` works for me. In automatic mode it was on the primary screen with 2 screens attached, but when attaching the 3rd screen and changing settings on it, the bar jumped to the new (non-primary) screen. This is not the case when setting to `Primary` (which was my expected default behavior).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments to the [@phemmer's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149477), it only holds for enabling panel. Desktop icons, menu etc. would still be not visible.

To actually fix this, do:

1. Right-click while in desktop and go to `Applications > Settings > Display`
2. Then in `Display` settings choose the proper monitor and toggle it as a `Primary Display` as shown in the image below.

[image: Display settings with Primary option toggled]

After doing that, all desktop utilities should be visible and configuring panel to be shown in a primary display would work too.