# Setting primary screen in middle of three-monitor-setting

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, xrandr, xubuntu

While googling to solve my problem I came across the stack post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149388/setting-primary-monitor-in-xfce). However, my setting is a little different:

```
-----    
| D |
| V |  --------  ----------
| I |  |HDMI-1|  |Notebook|
| - |  --------  ----------
| 1 |  
-----
```

The most left monitor is portrait, where the remaining screens are landscape.
Is there any possibility to do the following things automatically:
Set up the above setting, while having the primary monitor HDMI-1. With primary, I mean, having the Panel there but also applications that are opened, open there (on the primary monitor).
So far I only managed to get the most left monitor to be the primary monitor (with the troubles of having every new application opened in portrait mode on the most left monitor).

I currently use Xubuntu 15.10 and xfce 4.12:

```
xfce4-session 4.12.1 (Xfce 4.12)
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Since it will most likely result in a modified randr script, this is my current randr.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --off --output eDP1 --mode 1600x900 --pos 3000x428 --rotate normal --output DP1 --off --output HDMI2 --off --output HDMI1 --off --output DP1-3 --off --output DP1-2 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1080x248 --rotate normal --output DP1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate left --output DP2 --off
```

And here as a screenshot taken off arandr:

[image: arandr setup]

Where eDP1 is my Notebook.
Although DP1-2 is the primary screen, the panel is started on DP1-1 automatically and also new applications are opened there...
Please let me know, if there are more questions.

**EDIT**
I extended the script above to move also the panel to the primary screen:

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --off --output eDP1 --mode 1600x900 --pos 3000x428 --rotate normal --output DP1 --off --output HDMI2 --off --output HDMI1 --off --output DP1-3 --off --output DP1-2 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1080x248 --rotate normal --output DP1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate left --output DP2 --off

xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-0/position -s \"p=6;x=2040;y=264\"
```

This is different to the link mentioned by one of the comments, due to the current xfce version and the lack of the "output-name" property for each panel.

So the problems left are the following:

1. DP1-1 is oriented landscape, instead of portrait
2. There exist a small gap between the monitor and the panel
3. I cannot change anything to the configuration anymore, even not manually (arandr), because of the following error: "Cannot find crtc for output eDP1"

Comment: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6440

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, I was already aware of it. This doesn't work for me. I will update my question to show you my randr.sh script. The most left screen keeps being the primary, although differently indicated. I will also add a screenshot of the arandr application.